# Fragments and right design

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Sorry if the question was not clear. In my app I have 3 tabs on acion bar, further each of the tab has a separate xml layout with two fragments. For first two tabs the layout is similar, but the third tab has a separate xml layout.In first tab, I make rest calls and get the data to be displayed. The left side fragment displays folder list and right side fragment displays the file list. Tab2 is same but it displays the data from SD card. Its basically a file manager.

The third tab is search page which is totally different from the first two fragments.

Below is my question.

1. I want to know if I can use different activity for each of the tabs ?, is this the right design ?
2. Since I am using the main activty to create the layouts required for the fragments, I now have a problem with the third tab, reason being the xml layout and the fragments classes (code) are completely changed for the third tab. here are the contents of the xml file.

layout for first two tabs:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frags1">
   <fragment class="TitlesFragment"

            android:id="@+id/browse_title"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="320dip"/>

    <fragment class="ContentFragment"

            android:id="@+id/browse_content"  
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </fragment>    
</LinearLayout>

Layout for the third tab:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/settings" 
 android:background="@drawable/window"
 android:orientation="horizontal" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:baselineAligned="true">

    <fragment class="SearchFragment"                  
            android:id="@+id/search_title"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="700dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"/>

    <fragment class="SearchContentFragment"
            android:id="@+id/searchbrowse_content" 
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"      
            android:layout_width="match_parent"    
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>     
</LinearLayout>
```

So when I click from first tab to tab3 (search) the UI is renedered properly, but I can not come back from tab3 to tab1. To fix this I moved the fragments from the xml files and doing it in the main activity code. I am concerned because I am unsure whether this is right design or not.

Also, below is the code snippet.

```
switch(nTabSelected)
{
    case ConnectedConstants.BROWSE:
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.browse_title) == null)
    {
     setContentView(CreateMainLayout());
    }
    TitlesFragment titleFrag = (TitlesFragment) getFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.browse_title);
    titleFrag.resetCurPosition();
    titleFrag.setCategory(nTabSelected);
    if (bLoggedin) {
    titleFrag.selectPosition(0);
    }
   break;
```

Every time when user clicks on tab I inflate the xml for that perticulat tab.
The next question, I earlied said that I get the data from server using rest calls to update tab1 fragments, since I am using the list fragments for tab1 and tab2 , I just do setListAdapter, but with this I am trying to understand if I can implement a backstack or I need a new fragment transaction with every list item click and then add the fragment to the backstack.

Let me know, if my question still sounds unclear.

Thanks,
Harsha

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Narrow down your questions.

Comment: Please post logcat output regarding the "crash issue" you mentioned, if you want help with that.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

We were doing it all wrong, we were trying to inflate different xml files on click of each of the tabs, the easy solution is to have single XMLhaving all fragments and hide/show them on click of the tab on action bar.

We solved with one main activity, four different tabs, one main xml showing all fragments (8).

Thanks,
Harsha